# Cython: most efficient way to pickle and hash, and use binary data

Tags: python, cython

I have a function at the bottom of a Cython application stack that takes a Python object of a specific class, or a subclass of it, and creates a SHA1 hash of its serialized representation.

I am aware that something along these lines is already quite optimized:

```
import hashlib
import pickle

def _hash(obj):
    return hashlib.sha1(pickle.dumps(obj)).digest()
```

So there may not be much to gain from Cython. However, having to use the binary hash data afterward (the data object doesn't get used many times, but the hash function is called a lot), I would want to avoid wrapping that in a Python object.

Shall I:

a) attempt to use the C API for those stdlib functions (not sure if that can be done or if it even makes sense)

b) Use a `cdef` function and type the output (can I inline it? I guess not if the input is a Python object)

c) Just live with what I have?

Thanks.

Comment: Without profiling everything is just guess work. After profiling&seeing the bottle-necks you can decide whether it is worth trying cython.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. I know from profiling that this function, called many times, takes up a good chunk of time. I could experiment profiling the pure Python call with the C one (again, if accessible). Looking at the compiled C code, that one line generates a LOT of code. Would I be able to access the C API hash and pickle functions with Cython for comparison?